Compact set and the finite intersection property
I'm trying to prove the following statement:
A topological space $X$ is compact if and only if it has the following property: if $\{E_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is any family of closed subsets of $X$ such that any finite intersection of the $E_{\alpha}$'s is nonempty, then $\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha\in A} E_{\alpha}\neq\emptyset$.
This is my attempt:
Let's assume $X$ as a compact topological space, and let's also assume, by contradiction, that there is a family of closed subsets of $X$, $\{E_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ such that any finite intersection of $E_{\alpha}$ it is not empty, but $\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha\in A}E_{\alpha}=\emptyset$.
Since any $E_{\alpha}$ is closed, then $\{X\setminus E_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is a family of open subsets of $X$. Note that: \begin{equation}\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}(X\setminus E_{\alpha})=X\setminus\bigcap_{\alpha\in A}E_{\alpha}=X\setminus\emptyset=X\end{equation}i.e., $\{X\setminus E_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is an open cover for $X$. Since $X$ is compact, then there exists a finite open subcover $\{X\setminus E_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A'\subset A}$ such that $X=\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha\in A'}X\setminus E_{\alpha}$. But from there, we have: $$X=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A'}X\setminus E_{\alpha}=X\setminus\bigcap_{\alpha\in A'}E_{\alpha}$$ which implies that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha\in A'}E_{\alpha}=\emptyset$, a contradiction.
Reciprocally, let's assume the finite intersection property. Let $\{B_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ be a open cover of $X$, and we will assume that no finite open subfamily of $\{B_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ covers $X$. Of course $\{X\setminus B_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is a family of closed subsets of $X$. Let's assume $\{X\setminus B_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A'}$ as a finite closed subfamily, such that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha\in A'}(X\setminus B_{\alpha})\neq\emptyset$.
Since the finite intersection property holds, we have $$\bigcap_{\alpha\in A}(X\setminus B_{\alpha}) = X\setminus\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}B_{\alpha}\neq\emptyset$$
which implies that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}B_{\alpha}$ is contained properly in $X$, i.e., a contradiction. Hence, $X$ is compact.
I couldn't see any mistake in the arguments... But I don't know... something does not feel right for me, specially in the reciprocally.
Could someone, please, tell me if there is any mistake?
Thank you!

The second half is a bit problematic. To apply finite intersection property, you have to show any finite intersection of $X \setminus B_\alpha$ is nontrivial, which you doesn’t seem to have shown. Instead, you seemed to have only assumed that, which doesn’t make much sense.

I think now I saw my mistake. Thank you for your help.
